# Counting the lines of a long file not working correctly in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to count the lines of a very long file (more than `635000` lines).

I've tried with:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
```

and also:

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(fname))
```

Both work perfectly for files with *not so much* lines. I've checked making a 5 lines file and works ok, output is `5`.

But with with a long file, which exactly has `635474` lines, the output of both methods posted above is `635466`.

I know that the file has `635474` lines, not `635466` lines because I'm creating strings inside of the file and the last two lines are:

```
alm_asdf_alarm635473=.NOT USED
alm_asdf_alarm635474=.NOT USED
```

And also because if I open the file with `Notepad++` the last line is counted as `635474`.

What's the logic behind this? Why is it counting less lines that the real ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you use the same line separator in all lines?

Comment: Yes. When I create the string for each line I add a `\n` at the end. This means, for each line: `f_out.write("stuff\n" )`. And I write everything at once.

Comment: What does [`wc`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_wc.htm) tell you?

Comment: BTW: do you know that `enumerate` accepts a `start` keyword argument? `list(enumerate([1,2,3], start=1)) == [(1,1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]`.

Comment: I'm under Windows so I can't try that, @Bakuriu.

Comment: I wrote a file with 635474 lines but cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I do not know very much Notepad++, but it looks like a problem of looong lines that could be considered as 2 lines under one system (for example for printing) but still one single line for Python that only count EOLs. If you have the line number in each line, you could try to search the first line for which Python count is different from the inner number.

Comment: Your file gives `635474` with any of the two methods posted on the original post?

Comment: @SergeBallesta As I wrote on the post I added line counter and the last line of the file is `alm_asdf_alarm635474=.NOT USED` so the real last line is `635474`

Comment: Not the issue, but why not just do `len(f.readlines())`?

Answer (score 0):

If all your lines have same structure, you could try a program like that :

```
import re
num = re.compile('[^0-9]*([0-9]+)')
delta = 1 # initial delta
with open(...) as fd:
    for i, line in enumerate(fd, delta):
        m = num.match(line)
        if i != int(m.group(1)):
            print i, "th line for number ", int(m.group(1))
            break
```

It should be enough to find first line where you have a difference (delta is here for the case where first line would be internally numbered 1 and not 0). Then you could more easily understand where the problem really comes from with notepad++.

Note : if only some lines have this structure, you could use that variation :

```
        m = num.match(line)
        if (m is not None) and (i != int(m.group(1))):
```

Comment: Lines have different content after the `=`. This means I can have `alm_asdf_alarm635473=.NOT USED`, `alm_asdf_alarm635472=.HELLO`, `alm_asdf_alarm635471=.FOO BAR BAZ`, or anything after `=` . So I'm using your second variation but it doesnt work. No error is shown, but it never goes inside the `if`

Comment: @Borja : my regex should ignore everything after the number. If only part after `=` is different you should try initial code to make sure there is no mistake in the regex

Comment: @Borja : there was a typo in thé regex. You should try the fixed version.

Comment: Now works, thanks, and the output is `635474` as the `Notepad++` states.